# how to make simple PHP base quiz

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to make 15 questions, and any time user visits the page it shows random 5 questions and each question has 4 answers and 1 is the correct. The marks are 20, 15, 10 and 0.

How can i make it?

Comment: do you want someone to do it for you? as your first 4 words are "i want to make"

Comment: Maybe by hiring someone ? http://www.elance.com/p/landing/buyerE2.html http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone i want to known how to make it i dont known how to randomly show question other things i will be done

Comment: Do what you can. Ask specific questions when you run into problems.

Comment: Do you want something like this below link----
[Click Here to see an example of php quiz and somewhat javascript](http://oitexam.eu5.org) In order to take simple quiz give a look to login then login as guest in login section..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well nobody is going to write the full code for you I think, but as a general schema design, you'd want something like this...

```
questions table (q_id, q_question)
questionoptions (qo_optionid, qo_questionid, qa_option)
useranswers (ua_userid, ua_questionid, ua_optionid)
```

To get the choices for a given question (question 1 lets say)

```
select 
  * 
from 
  questions 
  inner join questionoptions on (qo_questionid = q_id) 
order by 
  qo_optionid
```

To get a report of the options each user chose...

```
select 
  * 
from 
  questions 
  inner join questionoptions on (qo_questionid = q_id) 
  inner join useranswers on (ua_questionid = q_id and ua_optionid = qo_optionid) 
order by 
  ua_userid, ua_questionid
```

Note that im not advocating the use of SELECT *, but its there for simplicity of example.

Answer (score 2):

I always find it best to start learning by Googling for tutorials.

Here are a few:

- [simple php quiz](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=simple+php+quiz)
- [select random list items in php](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=select+random+list+items+in+php)

I'm sorry to tell you go Googling, but I think the tutorials and examples you'll find there, will be far more helpful to you than **any** answer here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I agree, as he wants to do it himself, dive in and look at other peoples successfull code and see what you want to use/change/or not use.